# C# - Thread Abort and System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, multithreading, nullreferenceexception

I am doing a practise GUI Oven program using a thread, I am not sure if I should even be doing this because I want to interact with the GUI when the Heating process is ongoing. When I try to abort the thread by click btnStop_Click, it throws the NullReference exception:

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Please advice on how can I gracefully stop the thread. Thanks.

Code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private Thread t;

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            // button to begin heating
            private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {   
                if ((txtMin.Text) == "" || (txtSec.Text) == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter duration of heating");
                }
                else
                {
                    t = new Thread(heatIt);
                    btnHeat.Enabled = false;
                    t.Start();
                }
            }

           //stop heating
            private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Heating heat = new Heating();
                Form1 l = new Form1();
                l.Subscribe(heat);
                heat.stopHeat();
                btnHeat.Enabled = true;
            }

            private void heatIt()
            {
            // heat food Implementation that calls the 'Heating' class
            }

           public void Subscribe(Heating m)
           {
            m.heatComplete += SignalHeatCompleted;
            m.heatStop += SignalStop;
           }

           private void SignalHeatCompleted(Heating m, EventArgs e)
           {
            MessageBox.Show( "Done, please enjoy your food");
            return;
           }

           private void SignalStop(Heating m, EventArgs e)
           {
           t.Abort();
            MessageBox.Show("Heating Terminated");
            return;            
           }

public class Heating
        {
            public event HeatingCompleted heatComplete; // Heating Completed Event
            public event HeatingStop heatStop;          // Heating Stop Event
            public EventArgs e = null;
            public delegate void HeatingCompleted(Heating h, EventArgs e);
            public delegate void HeatingStop(Heating s, EventArgs e);

            public void startHeat(int temp, int min, int sec)
            {
                int totalSec;
                totalSec = ((min*60) + sec) * 1000;

                Thread.Sleep(totalSec);
                if (heatComplete != null)
                {
                    heatComplete(this, e);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Use default signal if there's no subscription to this event
                    MessageBox.Show("*TING*");

                }
                return;    
            }

            public void stopHeat()
            {
                if (heatStop != null)
                {
                    heatStop(this, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's in the Form1 class variable.

Comment: I am confused by the piece of code t.Start(); bool start = true; t.Abort();

Are you aborting the thread as soon as you have started it? I assume this would throw the error you are recieving, comment out that t.Abort() line in your btnStart_Click method and see what goes down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several remarks:

1. You should never use `Thread.Abort` to stop background tasks. This is a bad practice, as it forces aborting the background thread regardless of its state. Use a `volatile bool` flag instead, and check (every once in a while) if its value has changed.
2. It seems that your Form represents a UI for business logic extracted into a separate class (`Heating`). In that case, it probably makes sense to have only a **single instance** per form, and put it in a private field. Right now you are creating a new instance inside your `Stop` method, which is probably wrong (since I presume you already use it in the `heatIt` method).
3. For each `Subscribe` method, try to keep a habit of adding a `Unsubscribe` method, which detaches event handlers at some point. This way GC can collect your listeners after they are no longer needed, and you prevent adding the same event handlers several times.

I would expect something like:

```
private Heating _heating;
private Thread _workerThread;
private volatile bool _stopRequest = false;

void Start_Btn_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create the private instance
    _heating = new Heating();
    Subscribe(_heating);

    // start the thread
    _stopRequest = false;
    _workerThread = new Thread(HeatIt);
    _workerThread.Start();
}

void Stop_Btn_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // request stop
    _stopRequest = true;

    // wait until thread is finished
    _workerThread.Join();

    // unsubscribe
    // ** note that a better place for unsubscribing 
    //    might be at the end of the HeatIt method
    Unsubscribe(_heating);
}
```

And, in your background worker method, you will need to have a loop which checks if `_stopRequest` has been set:

```
void HeatIt()
{
    while (!_stopRequest && !finishedWork)
    {
        // do work
    }
}
```

Note that you **must** have a place in your worker method which will check the `_stopRequest` flag. Otherwise the only way to stop it is to Abort it (like you did), [which is not recommended](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation).

Apart from that, you don't need to stop the thread (like you did in your `SignalStop` method) once the process is finished. When `HeatIt` method returns (ends), the thread will also end, and there is no need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new instance of Form1 in your stop click event and so you are talking to a completely different t from the one in your start click.

You also probably want to have a single instance of Heat that you assign in heatIt and then use that reference in your stop click.

Also for background processing you probably want to look at the [BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to do the heavy lifting for you.